# Why does javascript sometimes output undefined variable

Tags: javascript

I have a small button which when pressed asks for a name and then adds the input to the URL which can then be processed by PHP. My code is below.

```
    function staff_prompt(url)
  {
  var url = url;
  var staffname=prompt("Please enter your Name below:","Staff Member Name");
  if (staffname == null)  {
  } 
  else if (staffname == "Staff Member Name") {
  alert('You must enter a value to continue');
  staff_prompt();
  }
  else if (staffname == "") {
  alert('You must enter a value to continue');
  staff_prompt();
  }
  else {
  var windowgo = url + "&staffmember=" + staffname;
  window.location = windowgo;
 }
 }
```

My Button code is below

```
onclick="staff_prompt('index.php?app=orders&page=action&action=go_orderedviewtype=<?php echo $viewtype ?>&orderid=<?php echo $orderid ?>')
```

Sometimes it works well, however other times it seems to go to "http://undefined....ect"
I cannot replicate the situation, sometimes it happens and sometimes not

I am thinking that maybe the code is not very good... why would the javascript not detect sometimes the variable 'url'.

Comment: use qunit to test your function http://qunitjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is problem in your code.

You are calling `staff_prompt()` function from both of your else if conditions & you have not passed the `url` in it as a parameter, so it will definitely take it as `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks - I guess that's why it only happened sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

Here URL is undefined. You are calling the function with an undefined parameter:

```
staff_prompt();
```

So as long as you get into the else if-s you would be getting the undefined url.

Change your code to `staff_prompt(url);` and you would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you call staff_prompt after an error, you do not pass it url.

```
function staff_prompt(url) {
    var url = url;
    var staffname=prompt("Please enter your Name below:","Staff Member Name");
    if (staffname == null)  {
    } else if (staffname == "Staff Member Name") {
        alert('You must enter a value to continue');
        staff_prompt(url);
    } else if (staffname == "") {
        alert('You must enter a value to continue');
        staff_prompt(url);
    } else {
        var windowgo = url + "&staffmember=" + staffname;
        window.location = windowgo;
    }
}
```

​
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/burlak/CsrTc/3/